# Why can't I call a method from another class in this loop?

Tags: java, list, class, methods

I'm trying to make a filter in the Catalogue class that will later print out 'parts' that have a price greater than the minimum price that the user has entered. However I am not able to call getNumPrice() (which is in the Part class) from the Catalogue class and I am not sure why? How can I fix this and what am I doing wrong?

```
   //The following is in the Part class

 public double getNumPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }

//The following is in the Catalogue class

 private double readMinPrice(){
        System.out.println("Enter minimum price ('-1' for no filtering): ");
        return In.nextDouble();
    }

 private void filter(){
        String type =readTypeFilter();
        double minPrice = readMinPrice();

       if ( type== "all" && minPrice==-1)
            showParts();
        else if (type=="all" && minPrice >= 0)

            for(int i=0; i<= parts.size();i++)
                if (part.getNumPrice() >= minPrice)
                    System.out.println( i+1 + "." +  parts.get(i));
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by can't call? Compiler error?

Comment: _"I am not able to call getNumPrice"_ What do you mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: Please show both classes clearly and also include the `main()`. Also, have a look around and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Always quote the exact error, rather than just saying you get an error.

Comment: It doesn't seem as if your `part` variable is defined anywhere.  Or `parts`, or many other variables. Please [edit] your question and replace the fragments of code with a [mcve], which we can compile and test.

Comment: Warning: you're comparing strings using `==`. Never do that; use the `equals` method to compare strings.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `parts` collection and you are calling `part.getNumPrice()` in your loop.

I don't see either declared in your code but I'm assuming `parts` is a field and you are trying to do something like `parts.get(i).getNumPrice()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the indexed part in your loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<= parts.size();i++)
   if (parts.get(i).getNumPrice() >= minPrice)
```